# How to change the JQuery Thickbox windows dynamically

Tags: jquery, thickbox

How to Change the JQuery Thickbox windows dynamically when the browser windows reduces or increases Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the size of a thickbox window by adding `width` and `height` parameters in `href` attribute of `a` element.

[Here's](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/#container-4) an example from Thickbox site that uses that parameters.

Comment: I think he needs the thickbox window also to decrease/increase when you open in a resized browser. Try this resize the browser window to 200x200 and click on the same example http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/#container-4.

Comment: I tried ur example it is working when the thickbox is loaded with the resized browser, but i need the thickbox to be changed when the browser is resized

Comment: You can hook up to the `$(window).resize` event and update the size there

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

[Thickbox dynamic resize of windows](http://manewc.com/2008/11/21/jquery-thickbox-dynamic-resizing-of-windows/)